# Getting SIGESV error in following cpp code

Tags: c++, vector

Getting SIGESV error in following cpp code, kindly check.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int t;
  cin >> t;
  while (t--) {
    int n, m;
    int sa = 0, sb = 0, c = 0;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<int> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      cin >> a[i];
    }
    vector<int> b;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      cin >> b[i];
    }
    int k = min(n, m);

    while (k--) {
      sa = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
      sb = accumulate(b.begin(), b.end(), 0);
      if (sb >= sa) {
        swap(*min_element(a.begin(), a.end()),
             *max_element(b.begin(), b.end()));

        c++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (sb >= sa) {
      cout << "-1" << endl;
    } else {
      cout << c << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The code asks for two arrays and swaps only if array a has a summation less than array b.
Getting error as SIGESV, also can take 'b' array as an input, what to do?

Comment: Stopped reading after first bug.  USE ```push_back``` to append a new value to the end of a vector.  Also, don't include <bits/stdc++.h>, it is not part of c++, but is a header that happens to ship with one compiler.

Comment: `cin>>a[i];` --> `cin >> a.at(i);` -- Then you will see what the issue is instead of getting a SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 0):

The size and capacity of vector a is 0 and never changes.

This code is broken:

```cpp
vector<int> a;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>a[i];
}
```

`operator[]()` does not grow the vector. You are assigning values to memory that does not belong to `a`.

You want `a.push_back(i)` at a minimum. What you probably really want is:

```cpp
vector<int> a;
a.reserve(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int tmp;
    cin >> tmp;
    a.push_back(tmp);
}
```

Reserving memory stops the vector from re-allocating. Not doing it in a constructor also stops default initialization of all elements.

The same goes for the `b` vector.

You also never change the values of `sa` or `sb`, but that shouldn't crash anything, it's just a logic error from what I can see.

The file as a whole is also rife with bad practices. "Competitive" coding sites actively make you a worse programmer.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `cin >> a[i]`, `a` is still empty, so attempting to access its i-th element produces a segfault. Resize it before with `a.resize(n)` or initialise it with the proper size: `vector<int> a(n);`

Answer (score 0):

When you know size you need while declaring vector you should declare vector like this

```
vector<int>arr(n);

vector<int>arr2(m);
```

this will create an vector of size n will value being zero at all indexes in vector at initialization.

Don't use <bits/stdc++.h> and trying coming up for better name for variables it will really help you as well as us. I know this is compeitive programming question but still.